# Ajax - Function fires without call or clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone explain why my ajax function fires without call or clicking?

```
<script>

$('#mudaSESSION'){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procura.php",
    data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>},
    }
  });

}

</script>
```

Any tips or help would be welcome,
Thank you. =)

Comment: Why wouldn't it, there's no click handler ?

Comment: You need to use an event handler

Comment: As given the code will give a syntax error.

Comment: You need to use click event link this $('#mudaSESSION').click(function{ your code ...})

Answer (score 1):

you didn't write click function here .You must write your click function like this:

```
$('#mudaSESSION').click(function () {



 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procura.php",
    data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>}
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i added the click =) But i still have the same problem :\

Comment: I don't have any syntax error , ajax just change the php variable and refresh the page. but i want to exec the function only when i click

Comment: please add your html also @Mario

Answer (score 1):

You haven't bound the element to a click event.

`$('#mudaSESSION')` should be `$('#mudaSESSION').click(function () {`

You also have a syntax error in the ajax call with one to many `}`.

```
$('#mudaSESSION').click(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procura.php",
    data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>}
  });

});
```

Comment: what is difference between ur answer and mine ?

Answer (score 0):

May some syntax error. Try:

```
$('#mudaSESSION').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procura.php",
    data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>},
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write click event for `#mudaSESSION`.

```
  $('#mudaSESSION').click(function()){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "procura.php",
        data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>},
        }
      });

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I see this ajax call isn't inside a function  this is why it will be executed.
If you want it to be executed on an object's click event add it in a function like this:

```
$('#mudaSESSION'){

 function magicCAll(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "procura.php",
    data: { <?php echo $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_SESSION['pagina'] + 1; header("refresh: 3;");?>},
    }
  });

}

}
```

Comment: Answer does not actually provide an 'on_click' declaration.

Comment: no but it is a function that can be called with onclick attribute

Comment: Completeness is the key. The answer alludes to an on_click event without an example. Keep in mind that this is not an advanced subject and could be misunderstood. Simply provide an example of what is described and call the function. Otherwise, the implication is that somehow `magicCall()` *is* an on_click binding.